# Php database format json for GoJs

Tags: php, mysql, json, gojs

I want to format `json` in this format for `js` library! GoJs expect json in this format:

```
model.nodeDataArray =
                [
                    { key: "1",              username: "Don Meow",   source: "cat1.png" },
                    { key: "2", parent: "1", username: "Demeter",    source: "cat2.png" },
                    { key: "3", parent: "1", username: "Copricat",   source: "cat3.png" },
                    { key: "4", parent: "3", username: "Jellylorum", source: "cat4.png" },
                    { key: "5", parent: "3", username: "Alonzo",     source: "cat5.png" },
                    { key: "6", parent: "2", username: "Munkustrap", source: "cat6.png" }
                ];
```

In php i try to return json like above but am realy new to json and my example dont work!

```
$users = $db->query("SELECT * FROM user");
$data = array();

while ($result = $users->fetch_assoc())
{
    $data['key'] = $result['id'];
    $data['username'] = $result['username'];
    $data['email'] = $result['email'];
    $data['parent'] = $result['parent'];

    array_push($data, $result);
}

echo json_encode($data);
```

My JSON looks like this:

> {"key":"7","username":"Vlada","parent":"4","0":{"id":"1","parent":null,"username":"Ivan","email":"office.asd@gmail.com","password":"qwe123"},"1":{"id":"2","parent":"1","username":"Martinu","email":"asd@gmail.com","password":"qwe123"},"2":{"id":"3","parent":"1","username":"Biljana","email":"asd.com","password":"qwe123"},"3":{"id":"4","parent":"2","username":"Emil","email":"test@test.com","password":null},"4":{"id":"5","parent":"2","username":"Elena","email":"test@test.com","password":null},"5":{"id":"6","parent":"4","username":"Bole","email":null,"password":null},"6":{"id":"7","parent":"4","username":"Vlada","email":null,"password":null}}

I try to replace `id` with `key` becouse GoJs need `key` property defined. My json is so so different and i need to format output like above json?

What i do wrong here ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to change the way you store it in array

```
$users = $db->query("SELECT * FROM user");
$data = array();

while ($result = $users->fetch_assoc())
{
$row = array (
    "key" => $result['id'],
    "username" => $result['username'],
    "email" => $result['email'],
    "parent" => $result['parent'],
);

array_push($data, $row);
}

echo json_encode($data);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are doing some wierd stuff in here

Try simplifying it to

```
$users = $db->query("SELECT * FROM user");
$data = array();
while ($row = $users->fetch_assoc())
{
    $t = array();
    $t['key']       = $row ['id'];
    $t['username']  = $row ['username'];
    $t['email']     = $row ['email'];
    $t['parent']    = $row ['parent'];

    $data[] = $t;
}
```

Or even more simple, specify the columns you want in the query, which will make it quicker anyway and then you have your array ready built

```
$users = $db->query("SELECT id,username,email,parent FROM user");
$data = array();
while ($row = $users->fetch_assoc())
{
    $data[] = $row;
}
```

Comment: Everybody gets a cookie.

Comment: Yummy. Can I have a cup of tea with that

Comment: Just as long as you don't mind it being cold when it gets there, sure. If not "iced"!